# How to run __doPostBack and catch download link in idHttp

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, indy, idhttp

i have used idHttp.post() to login inside a site
then i posted my information to the download page which is something like an archive (needs start date, end date and etc) and then sent submit button post
when i open the final response code (after posting submit) i can see the links for download, but they are something like :

```
__doPostBack('DG_FileList$ctl03$LB_Download','')
```

after i click on the link (manually inside a browser), http analyzer shows another post like this :

```
__EVENTTARGET         DG_FileList$ctl03$LB_Download
```

and i get redirected to a download.aspx page and download starts in the browser
i tried to Post this like other informations but i got an error for response code, am i doing something wrong ?  **can i even run the _doPostBack with post method ?**
if not, what can i do ?
Thanks.

Comment: Just about ANYTHING that a web browser can do with HTTP, `TIdHTTP` can also do with the right coding. ASPX postbacks are just HTTP posts like any other, so if you are getting an HTTP error code, you are not posting the data correctly. You already know how to analyze HTTP requests, so look at the actual requests that the web browser is making and then code `TIdHTTP` to replicate them as needed. Your analyzer should allow you to look at `TIdHTTP`'s requests as well, so you can look for differences between what a web browser sends and what `TIdHTTP` sends.

Comment: @RemyLebeau problem solved, thank you, after what you said about ANYTHING, i was sure it can be done with posting, so i went and checked every data and every line of code and i found i have a corrupted post information which it seems is not important and is only used for downloading! and that is why i never noticed it.